# How to close retrofit responsebody?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, retrofit, retrofit2, android-livedata

As I got the problem of memory leak using `okhttpclient` as discussed [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1556) and I updated retrofit to latest version `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0` also I tried to close body using `responseBody.close(); inside try{} catch(){}` block  as instructed [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2675) this way

```
appSettingService.getAppSetting().enqueue(new Callback<AppSettingModel.AppSettingMetaData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AppSettingModel.AppSettingMetaData> call, Response<AppSettingModel.AppSettingMetaData> response) {

                try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                    Log.e("res code appSetting", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<AppSettingModel> results = response.body().getValue();
                        if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                            saveToDatabase(results.get(0));
                        }
                    }
                    responseBody.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AppSettingModel.AppSettingMetaData> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

but I got this problem in lower version of Android as app crashes while running on `Api 16` and it says this error

```
                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Nullable
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:212)
                                                                                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldNames(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:159)
                                                                                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:64)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:328)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:311)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:68)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:46)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:36)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:168)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
                                                                                  at $Proxy0.getAppSetting(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your gradle here @IP Kaal

Comment: Can you also post the code where you creating the Retrofit instance and where you declaring you endpoints.

Comment: @Ishwor Khanai Did you got any solution